# read the header of a .pgm image file

Tags: c, format, scanf

I am attempting to read the size values from the header of a .pgm image file (mars.pgm), and assign the resulting values to the integer variables u and v using sscanf.

When executed the program prints P5 832 700 127 in the first line, which is correct (the 832 and 700 are the size values that I want to pick out).

In the second line that is meant to print u and v variables two very large numbers are printed, instead of the 832 and 700 values.

I cannot figure out why this is not working as desired. When using the small test program (located at the bottom of the post) sscanf picks out the values from a string like I expected it to.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
FILE *fin;
fin= fopen ("mars.pgm","r+");
if (fin == NULL)
{
printf ("ERROR");
fclose(fin);
}


int u,v,i,d,c;
char test[20];

for (i=0; i<=20; i++)
{
test[i]=getc(fin);  
}

sscanf(test,"%d,%d,%d,%d",&c,&u,&v,&d);

printf("%s\n",test);

printf("%d  %d",u, v);


fclose(fin);
}
```

small test Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void)
{
int a;
char s[3];
s[0]='1';
s[1]=' ';
s[2]='2';

sscanf(s,"%d",&a);
printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: Are your values separated by commas, as is specified your format string?

Comment: you could also change your code to read directly the first x characters of input file by using `fgets()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I advise you to make a small test: initialize your variables with a 0, for instance, and verify what value they are holding after read operation.

Then, try removing `,` characters from your format string. Check if it works then.

This behavior you see is happening because `fscanf()` and derivatives match the full pattern when scanning, which means if your source data has no commas and your format has commas, it may be ignored.

Comment: You are correct, the numbers should be seperated by spaces, not commas. I removed the commas but it still gives the same result.

Comment: As I can see, the first value in line is a string. Try changing your first format parameter to `%s` and the first variable type as well.

Comment: advice:advise::noun:verb. :)

Comment: @luserdroog oops, I'm not a native english speaker. Thanks for correction!